# Wordpress: How do i put a shortcode inside a shortcode?

Tags: tabs, wordpress

I am having an issue adding this shortcode as there are shortcodes within the shortcode as well (nested shortcodes). The parent shortcode works fine. But the ones that should come in the content are not. I am using the Tabs shortcode and widget.

Link: [Tabs Shortcode and Widget Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tabs-shortcode-and-widget/)

Within each tab content, I have included a unite gallery shortcode, but they are not reflecting on the site.

I will post my entire shortcode below:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[otw_shortcode_tabslayout tabs="3" tab_1_title="Bags" tab_1_content="[unitegallery bags catid=1]" tab_2_title="Wallets" tab_2_content="[unitegallery wallets catid=2]" tab_3_title="Clutches" tab_3_content="[unitegallery clutches catid=3]"][/otw_shortcode_tabslayout]'); ?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Kindly check : http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes

Answer (score 1):

To enable Shortcode as parameter to another shortcode, try to change **square bracket []** to **curly bracket {}** as below.

```
echo do_shortcode('[otw_shortcode_tabslayout tabs="3" tab_1_title="Bags" tab_1_content="{unitegallery bags catid=1}" tab_2_title="Wallets" tab_2_content="{unitegallery wallets catid=2}" tab_3_title="Clutches" tab_3_content="{unitegallery clutches catid=3}"][/otw_shortcode_tabslayout]');
```

Comment: Hi Milap, Thanks for the reply. I tried the above code the shortcode gets printed the gallery still doesn't show. `{unitegallery bags catid=1}` The above line gets printed

Comment: try to add single quote like : {'unitegallery bags catid=1'}

Comment: When I add quotes like the code you mentioned the whole layout breaks. The slider loads images on top of each other

Comment: That seems like css/jQuery problems then.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[otw_shortcode_tabslayout tabs="3" tab_1_title="Bags" tab_1_content="[unitegallery bags catid=1]" tab_2_title="Wallets" tab_2_content="[unitegallery wallets catid=2]" tab_3_title="Clutches" tab_3_content="[unitegallery clutches catid=3]"][/otw_shortcode_tabslayout]'); ?>
```

Try to do `echo do_shortcode([unitegallery bags catid=1])` where this `tab_1_content` parameter is being echoed